# how to check if a foreign key is set to a non existing primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Sometimes I have problems using my BD At Work. Usually is when i try to recover or update a table in Java with the session closed (the famous LazyInitializatioException ). 
And at the end, sometimes the problem is that exists a foreign key pointing to a value of a non existing primary key index. When it happens, the lazy entity doesn't load correctly.

So, is there a way to check if a table data has foreign keys indexes set to non existing primary keys ?

For a single column would be easy. But I mean for tables with about 10 or 20 foreign keys.

Im using postgres. If thats an answer especificaly for it it'd be much better. =]

Sorry for my bad English (not native).

Comment: If a foreign key constraint is defined between the two tables there is absolutely **no** way you can set it to a non-existing primary key. That's exactly what foreign keys are about. This sounds like you are *not* using real foreign key constraints in the database - which you should

Comment: I wouldn't say no way.  you can disable triggers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Java and those errors you mentioned.
Best solution is to have foreign key constraints created in db which do not allow to remove record if is referenced from another table.

If you must try:

```
select some_columns
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on (t1.id1 = t2.table1_id1)
where t2.id is null
limit 1
```

to check if such records exists.
If those tables are big there is no fast solution(usually ends with full table scan).

There is also possibility to do cascade delete or set null automatically using foreign key constraint. Read FOREIGN KEY part in [postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html)

Answer (score 5):

I usually use a query like

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE fk_field NOT IN (SELECT id FROM related_table);
```

and it usually work fine; I'm not sure whether there's anything more appropriate for this task (you don't have this kind of problems very often, if you use an ORM and/or always `DELETE .. CASCADE`)..

### Update

Of course, you can use this to directly query over many fk fields at once:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE fk_field NOT IN (SELECT id FROM related_table)
    OR fk_field2 NOT IN (SELECT id FROM related_table2)
    OR fk_field3 NOT IN (SELECT id FROM related_table3);
```

..etc..